# What biology knowledge can be applied in physics?

Tags: biophysics, biology

After asking a commensurate question in Biology.SE ([What physics knowledge can be applied to biology of organisms and ecosystems?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/what-physics-knowledge-can-be-applied-to-biology-of-organisms-and-ecosystems)), I wonder about the reverse direction: What biology knowledge can be applied in physics? This is the clip of Richard Dawkin (a famous biologist) talks about [applying Darwinism evolution into physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRTfgQG5Yn8). Is there any other biology knowledge like this?

PS: I don't know which tag should I use so I just pick one. Hope you will help me retag it.

Comment: This appears to be a fairly broad question.

Comment: @KyleKanos can you suggest me how to improve it? Cause I don't know where should I start. I have googled but it only show the applying of evolution.

Comment: I recall learning that physicists figured out why positive ions can enter cells even though the lipids composing the cell membranes can be positively charged.  The answer, it turned out, was that it increased entropy.

Comment: @honeste_vivere isn't that actually physics apply into biology, not biology apply into physics?

Comment: Yep, but I do not have an account on the biology page and do not know how or if biology could be applied to solve physics related problems.  I just thought you might find it helpful for your other page.

Comment: @honeste_vivere it's easy to register an account in it, and you don't need any reputation to give an answer. Anyway, thank you for the info.